# Add MVC4.5 webapplication to subdirectory of webforms 4.5 app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, virtual-directory, subapplication

i have a webforms 4/5 app named dating. I am trying to run an mvc 4.5 mobile website template application from a subfolder /m or /mobile with not much success. I am still learning and am struggling a little with IIS. If I simply publish my mobile app into the subfolder i get errors along the following lines :

```
"Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

Line 27:     <authentication mode="Forms">
```

when I set the folder to a virtual directory or convert it to an application i get the following error :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = IIS APPPOOL\Dating
LOG: DisplayName = AjaxControlToolkit
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: AjaxControlToolkit | Domain ID: 8
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/WebProjects/Dating/Dating/DatingMobile/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\WebProjects\Dating\Dating\DatingMobile\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\WebProjects\Dating\Dating\DatingMobile\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/m/03cc50e2/37a5ccf4/AjaxControlToolkit.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/m/03cc50e2/37a5ccf4/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/WebProjects/Dating/Dating/DatingMobile/bin/AjaxControlToolkit.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/WebProjects/Dating/Dating/DatingMobile/bin/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/m/03cc50e2/37a5ccf4/AjaxControlToolkit.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/m/03cc50e2/37a5ccf4/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/WebProjects/Dating/Dating/DatingMobile/bin/AjaxControlToolkit.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/WebProjects/Dating/Dating/DatingMobile/bin/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.EXE.

Stack Trace: 


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +210
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +242
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +17
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +122

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +12759734
   System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +214
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +334
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +203
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +152
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12880068
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12721257
```

I have the ajaxcontroltoolkit in my webforms app but not in the mobile app (browsing to the mobile path is when i get the error)

ive tried setting up a new application pool for my mvc application but it still wont work. if anybody can point me in the right direction id be very greatful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found that this is because web.config files inherit other web.config files in the parent directory even if the directory is a virtual directory or configured as an application. it should be possible to wrap blocks of code in the web.config with the location tag and specify a path, although i cannot get this to work for me

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692%28v=vs.100%29.aspx